# My wordpress site's pages broke

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-composer

for some reason my wordpress page broke.

usually the first thing on my home and about us page was a full width image with text on top. Now The page's Title with a white < div > is being shown on top.

https://malimo.co/unsere-vision/

https://malimo.co

This weirdly happened after I created a new page and built it with visual composer.

I tried tons of things like deactivating all plugins and I even reinstalled a complete backup of all files and database from 10 days ago. The problem still persists. The theme author is unresponsive and I have no clue what to do. I put tons of work into this site that's why any help or clue as to where I could look for a problem is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:
This is what the site is supposed to look like:

HOME https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnJhT.jpg
UNSERE VISION https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5NCt.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Notice in the code below, that the outermost div with the class "theme__section__overlay" differs in that the functional version contains the class `-image`, where as the non-functional one contains the class `-parallax`

The Unsere-vision Version

```
<div class="theme__section__overlay -image">
    <div class="parallax__wrap parallax">
        <div class="parallax__image" data-bg-src="https://malimo.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Screen-Shot-2016-11-13-at-11.04.19-1741x1080.png" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://malimo.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Screen-Shot-2016-11-13-at-11.04.19-1741x1080.png&quot;);">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Home page

```
<div class="theme__section__overlay -parallax">
    <div class="parallax__wrap parallax">
        <div class="parallax__image" data-bg-src="https://malimo.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Screen-Shot-2016-11-13-at-11.04.19-1741x1080.png" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://malimo.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Screen-Shot-2016-11-13-at-11.04.19-1741x1080.png&quot;);">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quite likely the case that you've missed changing a setting in visual composer to fix this issue.